# Problem interactions graphics when use drillthrough

Tags: graphics, powerbi, interaction, drillthrough, clique-problem

I run into the following problem:

I have a report with several tabs, in one of the tabs there is a table called "Employees" with different filters that alter that table, and other graphics such as "Level of English" that interact with the table "Employees" as well. In the same, the first tab, I have created a drillthrough (get details) in which it takes me from the "Employees" table to other tabs of the report.

The point is that when you filter through the "English level" graph, the "Employees" table is altered, it is given to obtain details of another tab, and when you return to the original tab where the "employees" table is, it leaves to be filtered by the graph "level of English"

Is there any way to fix it? In the sense that when returning to the tab the selections of the graphs are still active?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to un-sync the slier affecting the visual on the different page. On Power BI Desktop, click 'View' menu, select Sync slicers and then you can toggle what you'd like it to affect/not affect.

Let me know if this was helpful.